# Date Format issue with Excel for MAC

Tags: excel, format, excel-2011, vba

I'm trying to make the following code for mac, but it doesn't works(in windows this code works fine)... I'm originally programming this code in windows, for windows users, but now we have a new co-worker with mac, and that code is the only one with issues... hopes somebody could help me with this, I don't use mac and don't know why this happens...

```
    Private Sub DateBox_Change()
         Cells(6, 3).Value = Format$(DateBox.Value, "dd/mmm/yyyy")
    End Sub
```

The excel version of the mac is: Excel for MAC 2011 14.1.0, and the problem happens when the user input just one number in the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try:

```
cells(6,3).value=datebox.value
cells(6,3).numberformat = "dd/mmm/yyyy"
```